# Devise: logic using `admin_signed_in?` when Admin & User logged in on separate tabs in same browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, cookies, view, devise

In my Rails 3.2 app there are two Devise models: User and Admin. I have a comment partial form that both can use to make comments on a Post. However, I have included conditional logic with the *_signed_in? helper provided by Devise so that a checkbox appears for admins that allows them to make their comment visible only to other admins. Form checkbox code:

```
- if admin_signed_in?
  .pull-right
    = label_tag :internal, "Private"
    = f.check_box :internal
```

It's not a huge issue because it should never occur in production, but in development and staging I've noticed that if someone (tester, etc) is logged in as both an Admin and a User in different tabs on the same browser, the logic of my form doesn't work because (I guess?) those two tabs are using the same cookie/session info/whatever. The checkbox shows up on the User's form because the Admin is signed in on the other tab. It works fine if two different browsers are being used.

Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: Don't think so. It's a similar behaviour if you login to facebook as your own account vs a test user account. It replaces your existing session. It might be possible to use two different cookies for admin & regular users, but it's not a clean solution. Better thing to do is use multiple browsers if they want to be signed in as a different user at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to find or create a variable that can be used to determine if you're in the admin part of the site. A cheesy way would be to put a before filter in your admin controller(s) that sets an instance variable (@admin_site = true for example) then update your partial thus:

```
- if admin_signed_in? && @admin_site
  .pull-right
    = label_tag :internal, "Private"
    = f.check_box :internal
```

However it's considered bad practice by some (Sandi Metz for example) to proliferate the instance variables sent to the view. Also, it's a good idea to pass parameters in to partials explicitly as locals rather than relying on instance variables. (This helps readability and makes it easier to share them in general).

The facade pattern can help here.

http://robots.thoughtbot.com/sandi-metz-rules-for-developers

Edit:

Since using the facade I tend to spurn helpers in general, but you could probably do something like this:

```
#app/helpers/application_helper.rb
module ApplicationHelper

  def show_internal?
    request[:controller].in? ['admin']
  end

  ...
```

Assuming your admin actions are all in a controller called 'admin_controller'.

You can add more admin controllers if you have many, by adding to the array:

```
  request[:controller].in? ['user_admin', 'product_admin']
```

Comment: Also, don't assume this kind of thing won't happen in production. :)

Comment: Thanks! This was right on. For now I just need to use the one admin controller and through another SO question I found that I can access the current controller in a view with `params[:controller]` so I just used this helper with `params[:controller] == "admin/jobs"` inside.